# Como igualar variables sin asociarlas?

Tags: javascript, array, variables

Tengo una pregunta, ¿hay alguna forma de evitar que las dos variables cambien?

```
var A = [0,0,1];
var B = A;

B[1] = 1;

console.log(A); // 0,1,1
```

Hay alguna forma de que A no cambie con B?

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que el tema que buscas es sobre *inmutabilidad* donde:

- Tratamos de conseguir que algo no cambie, en este caso el valor de uno de los índices del vector numérico que muestras.
- Los únicos valores inmutables en JS son [los tipos de datos primitivos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Para este caso lo funcional sería el uso de **`Object.freeze`** el cual nos ayudaría a:

- Impedir que el valor que recibe se le agreguen propiedades o valores
- Que sus valores o propiedades sean modificadas

Quedando así:

```
var A = Object.freeze([0,0,1]);
var B = A;

B[1] = 1;

console.log(A); // 0,1,1
```

- [Object.freeze](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/freeze)

Comment: Object.assign , Array.slice incluso con el operador spread ; todas estas funcionalidades hacen un shadow copy si quieres hacer una copia profunda usa lodash

Comment: Gracias por las observaciones @JackNavaRow investigaré pues no se que sea lodash

Comment: Sería más simple **var B = Array(A)**.  El verdadero problema inicial es que **B = A** esta diciendo que son la misma zona de memoria y por eso cambiar B cambia A.

Comment: Siempre existe la posibilidad de que publiques una respuesta @JuanJoseBurgosVeiga

Comment: No creo que sea necesario, ya que tu respuesta es correcta. Mi comentario es un complemento ala tuya, incluso una opinión si quieres.